# initWithArray vs initWithArray copyItems

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a question what's the difference between these two methods on initializing an array?

I am assuming copyItems will provide a deep copy?

When would you use one versus the other?

Thank you!

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you for that link. I just read it and it seems like copyItems doesn't do a deep copy. I am curious as to when to use one or the other. I have always been using only `initWithArray`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray%3acopyItems%3a) for these methods is the first result (for me) with a little Google search.

```
initWithArray: copyItems:
```

has this documentation:

> Initializes a newly allocated array using anArray as the source of data objects for the array.
>
> **Parameters**
>   *array*
>   An array containing the objects with which to initialize the new array.
>
> *flag*
>   If YES, each object in array receives a copyWithZone: message to create a copy of the object—objects must conform to the NSCopying
>   protocol. In a managed memory environment, this is instead of the
>   retain message the object would otherwise receive. The object copy is
>   then added to the returned array. If NO, then in a managed memory
>   environment each object in array simply receives a retain message when
>   it is added to the returned array.

whereas `initWithArray:` has this documentation:

> Initializes a newly allocated array by placing in it the objects contained in a given array.

e.g.
<sub>Note: Since NSArray isn't mutable, my corresponding implementations aren't directly usable</sub>

```
 `array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array1 copyItems:YES]`  
 //would correspond to:
 array2 = @[
    [array1[0] copy],
    [array1[1] copy],
    [array1[2] copy],
    ...
    [array1[n] copy],
]
```

whereas

```
 array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array1]
 //would correspond to:
 array2 = @[
    array1[0],
    array1[1],
    array1[2],
    ...
    array1[n],
]

//or
array2[0] = array1[0];
array2[1] = array1[1];
array2[2] = array1[2];
...
array2[n] = array1[n];
```

Comment: I did read this, but I'm still not sure what that means. Could you give me an example of when you would use one or the other?

Comment: What about array2 = array1; ?

Comment: That would just make the *pointer* array2 *point to* the same memory as array1. Not copy.

Answer (score 3):

`initWithArray:` initializes a new array and places in it all the objects contained in a given array. This means that each object in the given array will receive a `retain`. Hence, if you edit an object in the new array, you will modify that object even in the given array. (see shallow copy)

On the other hand, `initWithArray:copyItems:`, if `YES` is passed as second argument, will provide a deep copy.

Beware that if you need to deeply copy an entire nested data structure then this approach will not suffice. (see the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithArray:copyItems:))

Example:

```
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
NSArray *a = @[s];
NSArray *b = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:a];
[a[0] appendString:@" there"];
```

after these lines the arrays `a` and `b` will contain the mutable string "hello there"

```
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
NSArray *a = @[s];
NSArray *c = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:a copyItems:YES];
[a[0] appendString:@" there"];
```

while after these lines the array `c` will contain the mutable string "hello" and the array `a` will contain the mutable string "hello there"

Comment: Actually in the second example it is exactly the opposite: 'a' will contain "hello there" and 'c' will contain "hello" :)

Comment: are you sure you read the example correctly? I just run the code and it works asa expected.

Comment: I just pasted the second example as-is. 'a' logs "hello there" and 'c' logs "hello" and that's the expected result. 'c' holds a copy i.e. a NEW object entirely. The append only affects the 'original'. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I didn't read my description I just read my code. Yes, clearly I inverted them, but the example is doing what I wanted to show. Now I'll fix the answer, thanks